Display and Extract image coming from backend in base64 format and Displaying it on screen
              <Label
              FontSize="14"
              LineHeight="1.43"
              Text="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Question, Mode=TwoWay}"
              TextType="Html"                                            
              TextColor="{StaticResource OIANavy1}" >
              <Label.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding 
              HtmlLinkOpenCommand}" CommandParameter="."/>
                                            
             </Label.GestureRecognizers>
             </Label>

above code is in xml file, we are binding .Question here and value for  "question": "uploaded images  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA", this
is the value coming from backed .
The value contains hyperlinks , text and images .
currently we can see a small square box in place of image what changes need to do so that we can see the image in replacement of square .
code to open hyperlink in ViewModel is
```
     private async void HtmlLinkOpenClicked(object obj)
     {

 int startIndex = CurrentQuestion.Question.IndexOf("href=\"") + 6;
int endIndex = CurrentQuestion.Question.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);

// Extract the URL between the quotes
string extractedUrl = CurrentQuestion.Question.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
await Browser.OpenAsync(extractedUrl, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);  }


Actually I want to implement the concept of innerhtml here , value is coming from backend and image is not stored locally still we want to display  images on the application.


Actually we used  a text editor on web application and these values are added there only in backend they are stored as string but when we render these value in mobile app we are facing this issue.
Mobile app is made in xamarin forms 


Please [edit] your question and fix the formatting so it is readable

now it is good to see or need to edit anything else

hi Jason please help me
